# Conditional creation of column with increment in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, increment

I have a large data set with around 1 million records and 80 columns. To speed up processing, I am using data.table. I need to create a new column based on a condition and I am lost as to how to do this in data.table

Below is the code for sample data:

```
set.seed(1200)
N_Blocks = 1348
cyc=200
City1 <- vector()
City2 <- vector()
a1 <- vector()
a2 <- vector()

for (a in 1:cyc) {
City1 <- sample(paste("City", formatC(a, width=nchar(cyc), flag="0"), sep=""),N_Blocks,rep=T)
a1 <- sample(0:1,N_Blocks,rep = T)

City2 <- append(City2,City1)
a2 <- append(a2,a1)
}

df1 <- data.frame(City2,a2)
```

Now the requirement is that for each city (currently we are having 200 cities in this sample data) and for a2 == 1 I need to create a new column that will have the total number of 1s divided in 12 months. So for example City001 & a2 == 1 with the seed of 1200 I get 671 records. So the new column **Months** needs to have codes **01-12**. So the 1st 56 records where a2 == 1 will have code 01 then next 56 records will have code 02 and so on.....and the last 55 records of City001 with a2 == 1 will have code 12 (so the total adds to 671). Something like splitting the selection of a2 for every City in 12 months.

We can get the City level summary of selection from the command -

```
table(df1$City2,df1$a2)
```

Can we achieve this using data.table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[a2 == 1, mon := cut(seq_along(a2), 12, sprintf('%02d',1:12)), by = City2][]
```

gives:

> ```
>           City2 a2 mon
>      1: City001  1  01
>      2: City001  1  01
>      3: City001  1  01
>      4: City001  1  01
>      5: City001  0  NA
>     ---               
> 269596: City200  1  12
> 269597: City200  0  NA
> 269598: City200  1  12
> 269599: City200  1  12
> 269600: City200  1  12
> ```

What this does:

- With `setDT(df1)` the data.frame is converted to a data.table (which still also a data.frame).
- The data is filtered with `a2 == 1` and grouped with `by = City2`.
- Finally, a new column `mon` is created by reference for the selected rows with `cut`.
- For each group of the `City2`-column, `cut` divides a sequence (`seq_along(a2)`; this starts with `1` and ends with the groupsize, i.e. `671` for the first group) in 12 (almost) equal parts. Each part gets a corresponding label (`sprintf('%02d',1:12)`). See `?cut` for more details.

The drawback of the above method is that the break with the lowest number of records isn't at the end. Which can be shown by summarising the result:

> ```
> > df1[a2 == 1, .N, by = .(City2,mon)][1:24]
>       City2 mon  N
>  1: City001  01 56
>  2: City001  02 56
>  3: City001  03 56
>  4: City001  04 56
>  5: City001  05 56
>  6: City001  06 56
>  7: City001  07 55
>  8: City001  08 56
>  9: City001  09 56
> 10: City001  10 56
> 11: City001  11 56
> 12: City001  12 56
> 13: City002  01 56
> 14: City002  02 55
> 15: City002  03 56
> 16: City002  04 55
> 17: City002  05 56
> 18: City002  06 55
> 19: City002  07 55
> 20: City002  08 56
> 21: City002  09 55
> 22: City002  10 56
> 23: City002  11 55
> 24: City002  12 56
> ```

---

To get the breaks with the lower number of records at the end, you can use:

```
setDT(df1)[a2 == 1, mon := cut(seq_along(a2),
                               {n <- .N/12; 
                                br <- c(0, rep(ceiling(n), round((n-floor(n))*12)), rep(floor(n), round((floor(n) - n + 1)*12)));
                                unique(c(cumsum(br),.N))},
                               sprintf('%02d',1:12)),
           by = City2][]
```

The number of breaks (`12`) from the first solution is replaced by a vector of breakpoints which is calculated for each group of `City2` separately in the part between the curly brackets (`{n <- .N/12 .... unique(c(cumsum(br),.N))}`). This part calculates the breaks in such a way that the number of observations aren't randomly distributed over the months, but such that the months with the lower number of observations will always be at the end.

In addition to the explanantion above, the part between the curly brackets does the following:

- First the number of observations in each group (`.N`) is divided by `12`. Often this won't be a integer number but a numeric with values after the decimal point.
- `rep(ceiling(n), round((n-floor(n))*12))` calculates the higher number of observations for the first groups (`ceiling(n)`) and repeats that a certain number of times which is determined by the decimalvalue of `n` with `round((n-floor(n))*12)`.
- The groupsize of smaller groups (breaks) is determined by `rep(floor(n), round((floor(n) - n + 1)*12))` is a similar way. `floor(n)` determines the size of the group, while `round((floor(n) - n + 1)*12)` determine the number of groups that is needed for the lower groupsize.
- The previous two vectors are put together with a starting zero (`c(0, rep ... )`).
- By using cumsum on that, you get a vector starting with `0` to which the groupsize is added at the end (`.N`). By wrapping this in `unique` you make sure you get unique break values. This is needed because when `n` is a prefectly rounded number (e.g. the outcome of 600/12), the last break-value appears two times in the vector.

The same check now shows that this is achieved:

> ```
> > df1[a2 == 1, .N, by = .(City2,mon)][1:24]
>       City2 mon  N
>  1: City001  01 56
>  2: City001  02 56
>  3: City001  03 56
>  4: City001  04 56
>  5: City001  05 56
>  6: City001  06 56
>  7: City001  07 56
>  8: City001  08 56
>  9: City001  09 56
> 10: City001  10 56
> 11: City001  11 56
> 12: City001  12 55
> 13: City002  01 56
> 14: City002  02 56
> 15: City002  03 56
> 16: City002  04 56
> 17: City002  05 56
> 18: City002  06 56
> 19: City002  07 55
> 20: City002  08 55
> 21: City002  09 55
> 22: City002  10 55
> 23: City002  11 55
> 24: City002  12 55
> ```

Comment: I'm still not sure that's correct, if I understand OP's question correctly. If you take  Row 669 as an example: `669: City001  1  07`, it should say 12 and not 07. The last twelfth of the City001 lines (where a2=1) should all be labeled 12.

Comment: @Mako212 Yes, it is the correct result imo. The rows were `a2 == 0` shouldn't get a month-value according to OP's specification. When you do `df1[1:669, sum(a2==0)]` it will return `326`, which is the number of rows not getting a month-value. Only the rows where `a2 == 1` should get a month-value. So only 669 - 326 = 343 rows should get a month value, which mean that `07` is the correct result for row 669.

Comment: @Jaap, Thank you!! This works !! It would help a lot if you could elaborate a bit on what is happening inside the {....}. It is a very interesting code and I am trying to understand but just not able to get it. Still long way to go for me......

Comment: @user1412 added an explanation, HTH

Comment: @Jaap, Thank you !! This is helpful!!

Comment: @Jaap, I had a another questions working further on this requirement and have posted a new question, link is    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45102793/code-optimization-generating-sample-data-based-on-pre-defined-variance    It would be a great help if you could have a look and suggest something. Thank you!!